# If $X_1,X_2...$ are independent, uniform random variables do there exist an infinite amount of $Y_n = X_nX_{n+1} < \frac{1}{8n}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X_1,X_2...$ are independent, uniform random variables on the interval $[0,1]$, do there exist an infinite amount of $Y_n = X_nX_{n+1} < \frac{1}{8n}$?

I want to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma, so I'll probably have to only look at even $n$'s, so that the $Y_n$'s are independent. If I prove there are infinite $Y_n$'s with an even index then I'm done.

It's easy to prove that there are infinite $X_n<\frac{1}{8}$ and an infinite amount of $X_n<\frac{1}{n}$, but I can't just multiply them and get the needed result.

Is it correct to say that the cumulative function for $Y_n$, $P(Y_n < t) = t^2$, and then just go from there?

Comment: Since $X_n$ is random, it does not make sense to compare it with a number. What you can say is, that $X < n$ with probability $p$ (if $p=1$ than we say almost sure).

Answer (score 1):

If $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and independent, the pdf of the random variable $Y_n$ given by their product is $f(x)=(-\log x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}.$ We have that $Y_n,Y_{n+2},Y_{n+4},\ldots$ are independent, so the probability that:
$$ Y_{n+2k}\geq \frac{1}{8(n+2k)} $$
for any $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ is given by:
$$ \prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(1-\frac{1+\log(8n+16k)}{8(n+2k)}\right) $$
that quite obviously converges to zero as $N\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ and $V$ be independent uniform$[0,1]$. Pick $c$ such that $0< c\le 1$. Draw a picture in the unit square, or condition on $U$ and argue by cases, to conclude that
$$P(UV<c)=\int_0^c1\,dx+\int_c^1\frac cx\,dx=c-c\log c. \tag{*}$$
You are right to consider $Y_{2n}$, so that you can apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma. Putting $c = 1/16n$ into (*) gives
$p_n:=P\left(Y_{2n}<\frac1{16n}\right)$.

Now the question is: does $\sum p_n$ diverge? If so, then $Y_n<\frac1{8n}$ infinitely often.